# How to show that a class/interface is the interface of a package in ArgoUML

Tags: language-agnostic, uml, argouml

Suppose I have the following package represented in ArgoUML:

[image: A package in a class diagram. Only one of four classes/interfaces is used by clients]

How could I emphasize that the `User` interface is the only component of the package that is known by external clients? For now, I use a note, but I think there should be a way of doing it more explicitly.

Note: it **should** be done in ArgoUML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UML, this is achieved using visibility: set the visibility to Public for "User" and to Package for the others.

ArgoUML (0.32.2), however, is unable to display visibility for elements (but it *can* display the visibility of packages themselves).
There is an option for visibility in Settings - Notations, but it seems to have no effect.

An alternative is to be selective in what you show in a particular diagram. Say your diagram describes the API; it would then only include "User" from this package, along with relevant public classes and interfaces from other packages.

Since you're up against a limitation of the tool, I would include a note in any case.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is what I am looking for. I need to present the private elements because I want to emphasize the relationships inside the package and the only component visible. So, I bet I will use a note.

Comment: Visibility is the right way to go for the basics.  An option to consider in addition or instead of a note is to define a stereotype like <<formalapi>> or some such and use it.  It has the advantage of a) being machine-readable and b) getting rendered closer to the element it modifies/describes.